# android cursor not closed error

Tags: android, cursor

I am using the following routine in my database adapter.  Everytime it is called, an error is created with a "Application did not close the cursor".

I don't see how I can close the cursor other then how I am, since I am not opening it in the calling routine.  This is used within a display adapter within a list.

I am calling it with:

int cnt = mDbHelper.dbio_rcount( "select count(*) from mytable where field1 = 'V' ));

```
public int dbio_rcount( String p_query )
{
    int v_ret = 0 ;
    Cursor mCursor = null ;

    try
    {
        mCursor  = mDb.rawQuery( p_query, null );
    }catch (SQLException e) {}

    if  (  ( mCursor != null )
        && ( mCursor.moveToFirst()) )
    {
        v_ret  = mCursor.getInt( 0 );
    }
    mCursor.close();

    return v_ret ;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you are getting an exception with the mCursor.moveToFirst() call which means your app is crashing before mCursor.close() happens..
Usually what I do is check that mCursor.getCount() > 0 before I call moveToFirst().. But that's just me.. I would suggest this:

```
 public int dbio_rcount(String p_query)
 {
       int v_ret = 0 ;
       Cursor mCursor = null ;

       try
       {
           mCursor  = mDb.rawQuery(p_query, null);
           if (mCursor != null && mCursor.getCount() > 0)
           {
              mCursor.moveToFirst();
              v_ret  = mCursor.getInt( 0 );
           }
       } catch (SQLException e) {
         Log.e(TAG, "sql exception in dbio_count", e);            
       } catch(Exception ex) {
         Log.e(TAG, "other exception in dbio_count", ex);
       } finally {
         if (mCursor != null) {
           mCursor.close();
         }
       }

       return v_ret ;
    }
```

Comment: looks like moveToFirst() shouldn't throw an exception.. Also I haven't used rawQuery.. You might give this a try and see if it helps at all though. Are you sure this is the cursor that is not being closed?

Comment: I think you're right about the exception, but it's happening on `rawQuery`, not `moveToFirst`. There's a try/catch around `rawQuery` that throws out an exceptions that are thrown. Your fix should work either way. I would, however, add a null check before `mCursor.close()`. If `rawQuery` is throwing the `mCursor` will be null in your `finally` block.